# create multiple dataframes based on my second row condition

Tags: python-3.x

I have some financial data that download from internet, the first row labels stock name, second row labels some charachter of the stock (eg:1M_CALL_IMP_VOL_50DELTA_DFLT means 1 month expiry and 50 strike)

Now I got (2M_CALL_IMP_VOL_50DELTA_DFLT, 1M_CALL_IMP_VOL_50DELTA_DFLT) and I want to group all stocks into 2 dataframes. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: welcome to SO, provide some input data and code about what you tried, errors etc

Comment: hi there, thanks for heads up, the currentdaatframe is like shown in the pictuyre, now just need to group the dataframe by there second row value